# Proof Relating to Area of Rectangle and its Side Lengths

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to prove somehow that if area of rectangle is strictly less than $4m^2$, then length of at least one of two sides of rectangle has to be strictly less than $2m$. I was thinking of proving this using the contrapositive, but would it be proving then "If at least one of two sides of rectangle is greater than or equal to $2m$, then area of rectangle is greater than or equal to $4m^2$."? I don't know how to go about approaching proving this contrapositive.

Comment: The negation of "at least one of the two sides has length less than $2m$" is "both sides have length $\ge 2m$", not "at least one of two sides of rectangle is $\ge 2m$".

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the contrapositive would be to prove that if "both sides have length ≥2" (as mentioned by @roger1) then  then area of rectangle is >= to 4m^2)

Suppose the sides are each 2m, in that case the area is 4m^2 which verifies the condition